# How to replace specific number of character from given string by sql query?

Tags: sql-server

Like:

```
s1= 'ldoed@dldkeo@fkfok@dkf@'
```

output like 'ldoedKdldkeo@fkfokKdkf@'

Replace first @ and third @ from string with character 'K'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using `charindex()` and `stuff()`:

[Fiddle demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10168)

```
declare @s1 varchar(100)= 'ldoed@dldkeo@fkfok@dkf@', @count int = 0 

select @count = charindex('@',@s1,@count+1), 
       @s1 = case isremove when 1 then 
             stuff(@s1, charindex('@',@s1,@count) ,1,'K') else @s1 end
from (values (1),(0),(1)) t(isremove)
```

[Fiddle demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10155)

```
declare @s1 varchar(100)= 'ldoed@dldkeo@fkfok@dkf@'

select stuff(stuff(@s1,first,1,'K'),third,1,'K')
from (
select charindex('@',@s1,1) first,
   charindex('@',@s1,charindex('@',@s1,charindex('@',@s1,1)+ 1)+1) third
)x
```

Comment: It should be first and third chars that needs to be replaced.